# How to use try catch around an activity in workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I want to call  a web service in Windows Workflow project using InvokeWebServiceActivity.

I want to call this activity in such a manner that if the web service call fails it should get logged and in the catch block i can write some custom code.

Now when the web service fails, which is on different VPN, my workflow breaks ..

Any Ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch the exception from webservice using FaultHandlerActivity, wrap the InvokeWebserviceActivity inside sequence activity, then use faulthandleractivity to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a FaultHandler activity. There is a container for all fault handlers you add. Each handler is bound to a workflow that executes as soon as the exception is caught. After adding the FaultHandler activity you define the type of the exception to catch.

Comment: Can you provide an example for how to user FaultHandlerActivity for catching exception from InvokeWebServiceActivity?